# Which Eclipse distribution to download

Tags: java, eclipse

I am newbie to Java. I need to build a Windows Desktop Application and use Java bean component and use Eclipse IDE. I searched the web but it is too many information and I am not completely sure how to do it. I understand I need the JDK and JRE before launching Eclipse.

When I opened the Oracle website,there are so many options and I don't know which one I need. 
For JDK, the website has `Java Platform(JDK)7u51`,`JDK 7u51 & NetBeans 7.4` and `JDK 7Dos`.

Also Eclipse download page suggests a lot of options.

Do I need  `Eclipse Standard 4.3.1`and package solutions, `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers`?

Hope someone show me the name of the package and program I need to download.

Thanks.

Comment: What Operating System(bit version) are you using ?

Comment: I think nobody downloads Eclipse Standard :-)

Comment: just don't download Juno

Comment: @Sandeep my OS is Windows7

Comment: @user819774: 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: @user819774 If you have Windows 7 64 bit, you can choose either Java distribution.  Just make sure that you download the same Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Apps:

- Java Platform(JDK)7u51
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

If you plan on building Web Applications:

- Java Platform(JDK)7u51
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Comment: I download it all. The Java Platform(JDK)7u51 is on c:\Program Files(x86) and the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers  is on another folder. When I create a new project follow a website using printIn that it has error for undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: You have to add the JDK to Eclipse and make it the default so that all future projects have it in the build path automatically. To do that, go to Window-->Preferences-->Installed JRE-->Add, then point it to the c:\Program Files(x86)\jdk1.7.0_51. Finally, check the box to the left of the newly added jdk to make it the default. At this point, it is easiest to start from a new project. On the other hand, it could be a legit compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) click the `JDK download button` located under the section `Java Platform, Standard Edition`.  The current version is `Java SE 7u51`.  On the next page choose your download based on your `operating system`, and whether you want `32 bit` or `64 bit`, named `x86` and `x64` respectively.  It doesn't matter which you choose (assuming you have a 64 bit processor), but you will need to make sure that `your Eclipse version also matches the bit selection you make here`.  Just so you know, the Java + Netbeans package just includes the IDE Netbeans, which you probably don't need since you are wanting to use Eclipse.

From the [Eclipse website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) just get `Eclipse Standard` for desktop Java development.  The other downloads have extra plugins already bundled with them, but if you require any of those extras you can always just add them using `install new software` from the `Help` menu within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Its better first download jdk 7 based on operating system(separate for windows 32,64bit and linux) and install now download 'MyEclipse 8' not 'Eclipse' because 'MyEclipse' has more built in functionalities.and it is user friendly than 'Eclipse'

Comment: Probably should note that MyEclipse is a commercial version of Eclipse.

Comment: I need a free software. Does anyone show me which library or progarm name for installing Eclipse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An option I am comfortable is:

1. Download and install Java JDK with nothing else included.
2. Eclipse Kepler is the latest version and it is quite stable.